# Using SQL Server Express for profit

Tags: sql-server, licensing, sql-server-express

The question is simple. I develop some software with the aid of Microsoft based products. I have purchased licenses for this products and they work well. The problem is that I need to connect the software to a DataBase. The sizes of the DB's are small - arround 4 GBs of data every 3 months.

Giving the fact that the software we are using is already Microsoft based I tried using SQL Express for this. Do I have to buy the license for Sql Express in this instance?

Comment: since the question was closed before I could answer: You should know that the Express Edition is limited in it's resources. You can use max. 10 GB per Instance according to this Microsoft [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/overview.aspx)

Comment: Try checking Azure,rates are pretty cheap and well with in your database size limits

Comment: Thanks anyway. On the other thread they said that it is ok. I checked today station that has been running for 2 months and we got approx. 700mb of data. My software just stores data and provides a graphical interface for the user. No biggie. The licenses did cost over 3k euros so I really did not want to invest anymore for DB's. The only added functionality that the DB's bring is that I can acces the data from multiple clients.